# ASUS STRIX GTX 970 (STRIX-GTX970-DC2OC-4GD5) Driver randomly failing, crashing

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

This is an issue I've had for months and no solution exists online, so as I found a solution today I figured I'd post the solution here for future people with the issue.

**PROBLEM:**

> While using a computer with a GTX 970 graphics card, once every few hours computer will make a "Device connected/Disconnected" noise. Screen will flash black, then revert to a very low resolution. DXDIAG will at this point show that it is running microsoft generic drivers. Restart will not fix issue. Only way to fix it is to reinstall the drivers, at which point it will operate a few hours before failing again. OS reinstall does not help, using older drivers does not help. Problem is persistent, RMA does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**REASON:**

> So, it turns out there is a driver being passed through Windows update, named NVDIA - DISPLAY - 21.21.13.7653 . Every time this driver is installed, the graphics card stops operating. When you reinstall the driver, it works until windows update downloads and tries to install this driver. It is possible its failing because it fails to install, or possible its corrupt, or possible its an issue unique to some computers. However, no matter the reason, each time windows update installs this driver, the display driver fails.

**SOLUTION:**

> First of all, go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System, click advanced system settings, then hardware. Go to device installation settings. Select no, and press save changes and apply. YOU ARE NOT DONE YET. This prevents windows update for installing the driver on boot, but not on shutdown for some reason, To prevent that, you must install the HIDE UPDATES TOOL ( http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-releases-tool-to-hide-or-block-unwanted-windows-10-updates/ ), select hide updates, and select all NVDIA drivers. Then restart, reinstall your drivers, and your graphics card will no longer crash.